# Border Mapping of Scatter plot

Tags: python, plotting

I have scatter plot and I want to trace the border of that.

for example:

Plot:

[image]

and I wanted it traced:

[image]

Or at least wanted to know the border points?

Also, is it possible to detect if any point exist on inside or not?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look into the literature on [Alpha Shapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape). They are a generalization of convex hulls and should give you what you want. There's a discussion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833243/how-can-i-find-the-alpha-shape-concave-hull-of-a-2d-point-cloud) Stack Overflow question about a Python implementation.